# Making icons behave as buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have menu icons where I need to make them behave as checkbox (on or off)
So When wrap icon is clicked it needs to wrap text and show the color change that wrap is on and when clicked again it would turn off

So I can get rid of traditional checkbox

I have code as

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@38,200,0,0" />

<style>
.menu{
 width:1000%;height:25px;
}
.input:focus{
    width:1000%;
    height:100%;
    outline: none !important;
    border:1px solid #1a73e8;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE;
}
.input{
    width:1000%;
    height:100%;
    outline: none !important;
    border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #719ECE;
}
</style>

<body style="margin:2px;">
<div class="menu">

<input type="checkbox" id="wrap" name="wrap" value="Wrap" style="vertical-align: middle;">
<label for="wrap"> Wrap text</label>

<span class="material-symbols-outlined">wrap_text</span>
<span class="material-symbols-outlined">undo</span>
<span class="material-symbols-outlined">redo</span>
<span class="material-symbols-outlined">save</span>

</div>


<textarea  wrap="hard" class="input">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</textarea>

<script>
$("#wrap").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $(".input").css("width", "100%");
    }
else
{
$(".input").css("width", "1000%");
}
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: $(_selector_).on('click',function(){ _wrap logic_; });

Comment: You can use css to style your checkbox + icon

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listener for the icons rather using checkbox as a selector.

```
 <span class="material-symbols-outlined" id="wrapText">wrap_text</span>

 let wrapText = $("#wrapText");

      wrapText.on("click", function () {
        $(".input").css("width", "100%");
      });
```